# Use of Undeclared Identifier error in CoreLocation

Tags: location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I don't under why the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'KCLDistanceFilterNone' and 'kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters' keeps coming up for my CoreLocation.m folder. There are also many more errors even when I deleted the ";" from select lines. Can someone please help?

```
#import "CoreLocation.h"

@implementation CoreLocation : NSObject 

- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return theLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[locationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

Also, what would I put in my CoreLocation.m folder to complement this and complete the location services for my application?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Have you included the CoreLocation.framework in the list of [linked libraries/frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)?
2. Have you done the import of CoreLocation.framework header?

   ```
   #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
   ```
3. I wouldn't have thought that `CoreLocation` is a good name for your class, because of the confusion between the above line, and your line that says:

   ```
   #import "CoreLocation.h"
   ```

   It should work (having both of those lines), but it seems unnecessarily confusing (and risks problems associated with `#import`'s feature that automatically prevents loading the same .h file twice).

   I'd suggest give your custom `CoreLocation` class (a) a unique name that doesn't risk confusion with the existing headers; and (b) a more meaningful name that indicates what it's doing (e.g. `CoreLocationUtilities` or `AppCoreLocationManager` or whatever).
4. Your alloc/init method line references a variable name:

   ```
   locationManager = [[locationManager alloc] init];
   ```

   It should presumably reference a class name, e.g.:

   ```
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   ```

   It makes me wonder how you defined the `locationManager` instance variable if you didn't get an error on that line.
5. Unrelated to your issue, I'm confused by your reference of your custom `CoreLocation` class being a `NSObject` subclass, but then having a `viewDidLoad` method, which is typically a view controller method. That seems to only further muddy the waters.

Comment: I'm still getting errors on this line: - (NSString *)deviceLocation; { and my first "{" at the bottom?

Comment: I've fixed the problem and have the coordinates.